# Remove error output from FPDF?

Tags: php, html, fpdf

Is there a way to disable the error messages in FPDF? I have my own error messages and I dont want the FPDF ones to show as well.

Comment: Output errors to a log, not to your clients.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the FPDF library's Error() function to:

```
function Error($msg)
{
    // Fatal error
    die;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The FPDF library's `Error()` function calls PHP's `die()` function:

```
function Error($msg)
{
    // Fatal error
    die('<b>FPDF error:</b> '.$msg);
}
```

To override this, you should subclass the FPDF class and override the `Error()` function in your class. Or if you want a quick hack, edit the `Error()` function to remove the call to `die()`.

Comment: I prefer this solution cause I don't like the idea of modify a known library (for in case it is upgraded). So I take the option of override the Error() function creating a subclass of FPDF and there I use to throw an Exception / write a message to the error log

Answer (score -1):

use this code to disable error reporting

```
 error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: This does not work because the error messages are not generated by PHP.